# Finding whole number in string

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

I have one input number. Let's say 545. Now I have for example this string: `string trying = "658;984;756;545;2000;5450"` as you can see there is `545` in this string, but there is also `5450` i want to find only my input number that is `545` but in my current code I also find `5450`. My current code:

```
MySet.MyRole = "658;984;756;545;2000;5450";
if (MySet.MyRole is null || MySet.MyRole.IsEmpty())
{
           setupSet.MyRole1 = true;
}
else if (MySet.MyRole.Contains(Number.ToString()))
{
            setupSet.MyRole1 = true;
}
```

Comment: `(";" + MySet.MyRole + ";").Contains(";545;")` or `MySet.MyRole.Split(';').Contains("545")` However, if you intend to do this check against the same roles multiple times, you should probably split it up and put it into a better data structure, such as a `HashSet<string>` or similar.

Comment: If you split into an array first, then it won't. And neither of the two ways I wrote in my comment will return 5450 as a match. I also look for the surrounding semicolons in the first case, and the second case doesn't have that problem at all. Both of these methods have downsides in terms of performance if you do this in a loop, but they should both do exactly what you want them to.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could just [`Split`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netcore-3.1) I guess

> Returns a string array that contains the substrings in this instance
> that are delimited by elements of a specified string or Unicode
> character array.

Then use [`Contains`](http://List%3CT%3E.Contains(T)%20Method)

> Determines whether an element is in the List.

```
var input = "658;984;756;545;2000;5450";

var result = input.Split(';').Contains("545");
```

Comment: I cant do Contains because then it would mark also my 'duplicate'

Comment: @ShadeBlaze you are doing the `Contains` on an array of separated values

Comment: `.Contains(x)` on an array will look for elements that are equal to x, it will not look for elements that contain x, so it will find 545 but not 5450. `.Contains(x)` on a string is different from `.Contains(x)` on an array.

Comment: Thank you for answear I have tested it on this code: ```string Trying= "115;12;122;11"; if (Trying.Split(';').Contains("1")) { Console.WriteLine("I dont work"); } else { Console.WriteLine("I work"); }``` I worked fine! So thanks! Take my upvote and approve :)